# How can I resolve element not found in AD CA?

Tags: active-directory, certificate-authority

I had to move our AD CA from server 2008 32bit to server 2008r2 64bit, both domain controllers too! I now know this was BAD.  Is there any way to resolve the "Element not found" in AD CA?  Or do I have to start from scratch and build a new CA on a member server?

Comment: Not sure how you moved CA and where you get this error, but you should have used [ADCS Migration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126170(v=WS.10).aspx) guide to move CA from one server to another. and yes, CA on domain controllers is very bad idea.

Comment: I used many different MS published guides.  I backed up the certificate store, also backed up the registry key, named the new DC exactly as the old one with the same ip address(fun times there!) All seems well except certificate templates in the CA mmc shows template information could not be loaded.  Element not found.  We don't run exchange, and have no applications that need a cert.

Comment: `Or do I have to start from scratch and build a new CA on a member server?` Whether you have to or not, this is what you should be doing anyway.

Comment: OK, I have resolved the issue with the AD CA.  After reading many posts on various forums, I uninstalled the server role, rebooted, and then reinstalled the AD CA.  The option for an Enterprise CA was now available, and I selected it.  The wizard finished, I still did not see any content in the templates folder.  I restored the back I took earlier, and success!  Thanks for all the advice.  I will be planning moving the CA from the DC!